# How to enable a user using a script?

Tags: sql-server, logins

I create a user with CREATE LOGIN...

sp_grantdbaccess does not seem to enable the user

How can I enable a user using a script?

UPDATE: GRANT CONNECT does not seem to work, maybe I wasn't clear enough,
This is a SQL user (not Windows user) on SQL Server 2014, I'm looking at the main "Security-->Logins" tab that is common to all databases...

[image]

Comment: What the error you are getting? Pls follow the link here:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2038/understanding-how-a-user-gets-database-access-in-sql-server/

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: You seem to be confusing two different concepts: server logins and database users. You may want to take a look at this section of the manual: [Principals (Database Engine)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181127.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access a database using a login you created, you need some decisions to make,
first : you have to create a user in database for the login you created, it could be a same name or a different name for it.
you also need to decide what amount of permissions you need for the login,

the sample below is for creating a login with a specific password, that is going to access adventureworks2012 with db_datareader permission over database:

```
USE [master] 
GO 
CREATE LOGIN [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'123', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF 
GO 
USE [AdventureWorks2012] 
GO 
CREATE USER [test] FOR LOGIN [test] 
GO 
USE [AdventureWorks2012] 
GO 
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [test] GO
```

Answer (score 0):

There is few steps to Enable Database Users though TSQL

**step 1**

```
Use databasename
 GO

 SELECT 
    principal_id AS [Principal ID]
     ,name AS [Database User Name]
     ,type AS [User Type]
     ,type_desc AS [User Type Description]
 FROM sys.database_principals 
    WHERE TYPE IN ('G','U','S')
         ORDER BY type ASC
 GO
```

Example:-It shows all user in database and the output will be like that .The output will depend on your system configuration.

```
Principal ID      Database User Name    User Type   User Type Description

1                       dbo                 S                 SQL_User 

4                       sys                 s                 SQL_User
8              INTRANET\DBAdmins            G            WINDOWS_GROUP
9               INTRANET\TMAdmin            U             WINDOWS_USER


where  
     S = SQL_USER
     U = WINDOWS_USER
     G = WINDOWS_GROUP
```

**step 2**

You can find all the users within the database which are disabled either by using SSMS or using TSQL.

```
USE databasename
 GO

 SELECT 
    SU.NAME
    ,DP.principal_id
    ,dp.type
    ,dp.type_desc
    ,su.hasdbaccess
 FROM sys.database_principals DP
 INNER JOIN sys.sysusers SU ON dp.principal_id = SU.uid
    WHERE DP.TYPE IN ('G','U','S')
 AND SU.hasdbaccess = 0
    ORDER BY DP.TYPE ASC
 GO
```

for example The output comes like this way

```
NAME                  principal_id     type     type_desc   hasdbaccess
INFORMATION_SCHEMA    3             S        SQL_USER    0
 sys                       4                S        SQL_USER    0
```

where hasdbaccess=0

**Step 3**

To enable all Users who are disabled within the user database

```
Use databasename
 GO

 SELECT 'GRANT CONNECT TO [' + SU.name + '];' FROM sys.database_principals DP
 INNER JOIN sys.sysusers SU ON dp.principal_id = SU.uid
 WHERE DP.TYPE IN ('G','U')
 AND SU.hasdbaccess = 1
 GO

Sample Output
 
GRANT CONNECT TO [Domain\User1];
 GRANT CONNECT TO [Domain\AdminGroup];
```

Open a New Query window and run the above script under the context of the database to **GRANT CONNECT** to user and to resolve the issue.

for your further ref :- http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/How-to-Enable-Database-Users-in-SQL-Server/